# Word or phrase describing "conforming to mean or average"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I am exploring a statistical experiment in which participants are asked for their rating of an idea (say from 1 to 10).  Then they are shown the average rating of all other participants, and given an opportunity to change their own rating.

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe the participants who change their own rating to a rating closer to the average.

`Confirmation bias` seems similar, but it does not capture the exact idea.

Comment: It's ***conformism,*** just that. Unless you want to say herd-mentality or such :)

Comment: Actually it is "normal" i.e., conforming to the norm.

Comment: Second-guessing and changing one's mind can be described as "Cognitive dissonance". However, it doesn't connote the conformism.

Comment: actually cognitive dissonance is more about not changing your mind, even when contradictions are pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider "[peer pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_pressure)."

Answer (score 1):

**Sequacious**: [1.
following with smooth or logical regularity.
2.
Archaic. following, imitating, or serving another person, especially unreasoningly.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sequacious)

& https://www.boundless.com/psychology/social-psychology/social-influence/group-behavior/

**deindividuation**  a concept in social psychology that is generally thought of as the losing of self-awareness in groups

**groupthink**   A psychological phenomenon that occurs within groups of people, in which the desire for harmony in a decision-making group overrides a realistic appraisal of alternatives.